# Union of two sets with Kleene star proof

Tags: formal-languages

I'm trying to do the following demonstration, but I don't know where to start to formally demonstrate it:

Given $\Sigma=\lbrace a,b\rbrace ,L_1,L_2\subseteq \Sigma^*$ and

- $L_1 = \lbrace w\in\Sigma^* / |w|_a = 2 \rbrace$
- $L_2 = \lbrace w\in\Sigma^* / |w|_a = 2\cdot k ,k\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace$

**Prove:** $(L_1 \cup \lbrace b \rbrace)^* = L_2$

I get the idea that is true since Kleene's star will always take items from $ L_1 $ and this one always has an even amount of a's. Any idea how to prove it formally? :P

Comment: Your argument basically shows one direction: $(L_1\cup\{b\})^*\subseteq L_2$. For the other direction, given a $w\in L_2$, cut it after every second $a$...

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of cutting it :'/

Comment: You either get only letters $b$, or you get $w=w_1w_2\dots w_k$ with $w_i\in L_1$.